# Проверка возраста

Tags: javascript, html

Есть input с датой рождения:

```
<input type="date" name="Date" placeholder="Дата рождения" id="Date" onblur=""/>
```

Хочу сделать, что при потере фокуса, если возраст пользователя менее 18 поле подсвечивалось красным и рядом была ошибка

Comment: Как может быть дата меньше числа?

Comment: @Anamnian очепяточка, если его возраст менее 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то такое пойдёт?)

```js
$('#Date').bind('blur', function(){
  var d = new Date();
  var InputVal = $(this).val().split('-')[0];
  var ThisYear = d.getFullYear();
  if(ThisYear-InputVal<18) {
    $('.res').text('Вам нельзя покупать алкоголь, пока Вам не исполниться 18');
  } else {
    $('.res').text('Вам можно покупать алкоголь, вам же '+(ThisYear-InputVal));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="Date" placeholder="Дата рождения" id="Date" onblur=""/>
<div class="res"></div>
```

Comment: Ваш код работает только с одним форматом даты и не учитывает разницу месяцев/дней.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" class="bithday">


  const input = document.body.querySelector('.bithday');

  input.addEventListener('keyup', (evt) => {

    const value = input.value;
    /* убираем все символы маски ввода c разделением через дефиз (05-12-2002) */
    const valueWithoutDash = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');

    /* проверка только после ввода полной даты */
    if (valueWithoutDash.length === 8) {
    /* проверка на корректность введенной даты, чтобы не было числа 77 или месяца 99 и т.п. Основана на свойстве объекта даты - автоисправление */
      const arrBirth = value.split("-");
      const birth = new Date(arrBirth[2], arrBirth[1] - 1, arrBirth[0]);
      let today = new Date();

      if ((birth.getFullYear() != arrBirth[2]) || (birth.getMonth() + 1 != arrBirth[1]) || (birth.getDate() != arrBirth[0])) {
        /* действие на случай введения некорректной даты */
        return;
      }


      const yearsOld18 = new Date();
      yearsOld18.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() - 18)


      if (birth > yearsOld18) {
        /* действие на случай если меньше 18 лет */
      }
    }
  })
```